# Pandas dataframe resample aggregation by mills too slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

Given this test data:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

data = {'date': ['2014-05-01 18:47:05.069722', '2014-05-01 18:47:05.119994', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.178768', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.230071', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.230071', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.280592', '2014-05-03 18:47:05.332662', '2014-05-03 18:47:05.385109', '2014-05-04 18:47:05.436523', '2014-05-04 18:47:05.486877'], 
        'battle_deaths': [34, 25, 26, 15, 15, 14, 26, 25, 62, 41], 'prisioners': [3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 6, 4, 5, 2, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'battle_deaths', 'prisioners'])
```

Set index datetime:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']), drop=True)
del df['date']
```

It works when I want to resample to the milliseconds, but it takes too long...

```
timeit df.resample('1L').sum()
```

I guess is because is aggregating all the milliseconds with NaN data, but when I drop it ..

```
timeit df.resample('1L').sum().dropna()
```

It takes even longer

[image]

guessing again that the dropna is done at the end... There is any way which by dropping the NaN samples will accelerate the process?

Answer (score 3):

It appears you don't really want to use resampling.  You are immediately throwing away the resampled data.  I think what you actually need is to simply [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) records in the same millisecond.  That can be accomplished with:

#### Truncate to milliseconds and group by

```
df['milliseconds'] = df['date'].str[:-3]
grouped_and_summed = df.groupby(df.milliseconds).sum()
```

#### Test Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'date': ['2014-05-01 18:47:05.069722', '2014-05-01 18:47:05.119994',
                 '2014-05-02 18:47:05.178768', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.230071',
                 '2014-05-02 18:47:05.230071', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.280592',
                 '2014-05-03 18:47:05.332662', '2014-05-03 18:47:05.385109',
                 '2014-05-04 18:47:05.436523',
                 '2014-05-04 18:47:05.486877'],
        'battle_deaths': [34, 25, 26, 15, 15, 14, 26, 25, 62, 41],
        'prisioners': [3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 6, 4, 5, 2, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'battle_deaths', 'prisioners'])

df['milliseconds'] = df['date'].str[:-3]
print(df.groupby(df.milliseconds).sum())
```

#### Results:

```
                         battle_deaths  prisioners
milliseconds                                      
2014-05-01 18:47:05.069             34           3
2014-05-01 18:47:05.119             25           4
2014-05-02 18:47:05.178             26           3
2014-05-02 18:47:05.230             30           4
2014-05-02 18:47:05.280             14           6
2014-05-03 18:47:05.332             26           4
2014-05-03 18:47:05.385             25           5
2014-05-04 18:47:05.436             62           2
2014-05-04 18:47:05.486             41           8
```